# unix_timestamp not returning expected output

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I am firing following query against mysql db and it's not working as per my expectations :-

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(exprTime) FROM config
```

Type of exprTime is datetime. Table contains following records

[image]

And the result, I am getting is as follows :-

[image]

I am expecting 36000 and 43200 as output but, I am getting 0. What am I missing here ?

Apologizing for such silly question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which type exprTime is?

Comment: exprTime is the name of the column, whose type is date time and whose values are shown in the image given above.

Answer (score 0):

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer.

`0000-00-00` - is less date than `1970-01-01` and can't be returned as unsigned integer. You can use [TIME_TO_SEC()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec):

```sql
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC("0000-00-00 10:00:00")
```

will return value 36000.